# SwiftUI: listRowInsets not working as expected

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

`listRowInsets(_:)` is not working as expected when using `List()` and `List(Data,id)`. in *Example 1* below works perfectly with zero insets, while in *Example 2* it does nothing.

---

### Example 1:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Color.red
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            Color.blue
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            Color.yellow
                .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

*The Result:*

[image: Example 1]

---

### Example 2

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .yellow]
    var body: some View {
        List(colors, id: \.self) { color in
            color.listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

*The Result:*

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume the reason is in used constructors. The `.listRowInsets` by documentation affects view being placed in List (directly).

The following works

```
var colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .yellow]
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
            color.listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great find! Fwiw, while this solution works, I'm wondering if the other way failing is just a bug or intended behavior. The example in the discussion on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/listrowinsets(_:) mentioned setting a list inset as @Mohammed did..

Comment: @FrederikWinkelsdorf perhaps it’s been updated - the documentation page you linked now uses a ForEach inside the List in their example

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the solution for your case but this was to a very similar mine so I figured I'd post it here too for the others.

I had similar problem: I set the `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` but still had vertical spacing around the content in some cases. Apparently SwiftUI sets a minimum height for the list rows and if content takes less space then some gaps might be visible. The solution is to remove this minimum height:

```
List {
  ...
}
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Asperi's answer, if you have sections, you need to apply the listRowInsets view modifier to the section, otherwise the setting is also going to be ignored.